# border radius not working in opera browser-11.1

Tags: html, css, opera

i am writing an application using html,css and javascript. i have set border radius of button to have rounded corner but which is not working in opera browser. but same i have tested in chrome it works. please do give some suggestion or help on this. here is [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rashmi/YHGcC/3/)

Comment: What version of Opera? `border-radius` is supported since Opera 10.5, I believe. Open the following links in any browser to test support for this. Example site: http://people.opera.com/zibin/border_radius_zibin.html  Screenshot version of how the example site *should* look: http://people.opera.com/zibin/border_radius_screenshot.html

Comment: @nybbler thanks for yor reply. have you seen the page source of those webpages if not please have look

Comment: @rashmi, I think some of the issues are with your css. You haven't assigned all the necessary elements for the border style to work on your button element. Try updating your button style to button{ border:1px solid #fff; }

Comment: is there way to set border radius to work in opera please some one give me right solution

Comment: @Dan ya i got to now that Dan. now its working fine.

Comment: @rashmi, good to hear mate. As for the :focus class, I'm sure that will work the way you want it to. You can always style the button element with the following: button:visited, button:hover and button:active (button active is the down state of the mouse click or finger press (mobile device)).

Comment: @rashmi: I have looked at the source and it's what should be expected. One site with CSS and HTML elements to create rounded corner controls and another site essentially containing only a single image of the expected display result.

Comment: http://demo.superdit.com/jquery/circle_gallery/ This works with images even on opera.

Answer (score 3):

Rounded Corner or all browser you want to use folloing method

```
#divId{
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -o-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Its work for me perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Border-radius css style is not fully cross-browser supported. Opera is one browser that does not offer support.

See: http://www.westciv.com/iphonetests/

Comment: According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_pr_border-radius.asp), however, it should work.

Comment: @blake305 According to w3schools, their site is useful :)

Comment: You don't say. Always good to have conflicting information on the web =P

Comment: @Dan thanks for your reply. have you looked in to my code. in my code i set border color to black initially and white on focus. but i dont see that change over. all the 4 cells will have border on page load (opera) any idea why is it happening so .....

Comment: @Dan but keep in mind, the url talks about development for the iphone.

Comment: Rashmi, for a start as, you will need to declare the styles for the border correctly, then work from there. Try something like: button{
 border:1px solid #fff;
}

Comment: @rashmi, I also noticed in your CSS you have only got the rounded corner style in your :focus state. You will need to add the class to the 'static' state for it to be visible (other than on focus). Also, I don't know if :focus is the most ideal action for what you want - what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

First, did you try `-o-border-radius`? Second did you try on a plain div? Sometimes form elements reject certain styles. Otherwise it isn't support (opera10 didn't have it).

Comment: opera implements border-radius. There is no need for the vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0):

[Border radius in Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-border-background-boxshadow/#border-radius) with other demos related to Opera.

```
button {
 background:#000;   
 color:#fff;
 border-radius: 15px;  
}
```

Comment: if i set border to none  it will hide the border which i dont want

Comment: Then are you saying you want a square border on buttons which become round when clicked? kind of strange. no? If you want always the border to be round you can make it round for the neutral state of the button. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

In Opera you can use this:

```
.className {
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: You should use 4 spaces for highlight code instead of `>` which is for quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found out that although border-radius is supported in Opera, it doesn't quite work with buttons.
But I managed to make it work, and achieved almost the same results. Here's my solution.
Just recreate behavior of the button with following style:

```
button {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
button:hover, button:active, button:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
button:active { border-style: inset; }
```

The thing is, that border-radius works, when you change border-style property. The behavior of Firefox, for example, when you just use border-radius, looks like it's using **border-style: outset** for normal behavior of button, and **border-style: inset**, when the button is clicked.
There are only 2 extra lines to make it work in Opera almost the same way as in other browsers.